# Removing specific items from a list but keeping some in python

Tags: python, list

I have a large data set that produces a list after using the re.finditer function to find all instances of a certain character. Sample list shown here:

`[41, 64, 87, 105, 713, 736, 759, 777, 1385, 1408, 1431, 1449, 2057, 2080, 
 2103, 2121, 2729, 2752, 2775, 2793,...]`

I need to delete all but every 4th item. So I need to delete the character at index 41, 64, and 87 but not 105. Delete 713, 736, and 759 but not 777. etc.

I am using python on a Mac OS 10.12.

UPDATE:

So now I have this new list `a=[105,777,1449,2121,2793]` and I wish to replace the indices of a textfile which I have imported into a variable. Could I just do:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(a):
     raw_text[item] = "new character/string"
```

Comment: Can you please write the expected output. Note that the result of `finditer` is **not** a string, but a list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your description, you want to remove all but every fourth element. You can do this with a **slicing** operator:

```
data[3::4]
```

Here **`3`** is the **start index** since the first index we are interested in, is at `3`. The **`4`** means that we take **hops of 4**.

This generates:

```
>>> data[3::4]
[105, 777, 1449, 2121, 2793]
```

In case you are working with an **iterable** (not a list, tuple,...), you can use `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

islice(data,3,None,4)
```

Here the `None` is semantically used as the *stop index*. Since we don't want to stop at a certain index, we use `None`. This will generate:

```
>>> list(islice(data,3,None,4))
[105, 777, 1449, 2121, 2793]
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Now that I have the new list of [105,777,1449,2121,2793] how would I replace items in a dataset based on those indices?

Comment: @Dorilds: can you update your question and provide more context? Or start a new question?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [41, 64, 87, 105, 713, 736, 759,
     777, 1385, 1408, 1431, 1449, 2057, 
     2080, 2103, 2121, 2729, 2752, 2775, 2793]

b = a[3::4]
print(b)

# Output:
# [105, 777, 1449, 2121, 2793]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its little different but if you start reverse indexing then it ll give you same

```
In [29]: s = d[::-4]

In [30]: s
Out[30]: [2793, 2121, 1449, 777, 105]

In [31]: s.reverse()

In [32]: s
Out[32]: [105, 777, 1449, 2121, 2793]
```